# Remove Vertical Spacing from React Native Text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have made a CustomText component to use Poppins font family. But while using it I am getting vertical space which eventually gets bigger with fontsize creating unnecessary space between two CustomText components.

I tried to use padding:0,margin:0,line-height:undefined | fontSize but none of them are working here.
Here is my CustomText code:

```js
const CustomText: React.FC<CustomTextProps> = ({

  style,
  isBold,
  isItalic,
  fontSize,
  color,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  fontSize ??= fontSizes.xsm;
  const combinedStyles = [
    styles.defaultText,
    style,
    isBold && styles.boldText,
    isItalic && styles.italicText,
    { fontSize: fontSize },
    { color: color ?? "black" },
  ];

  return <Text style={combinedStyles} {...restProps} />;
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  defaultText: {
    fontFamily: "Poppins-Regular",
  },
  boldText: {
    fontFamily: "Poppins-Bold",
  },
  italicText: {
    fontFamily: "Poppins-Italic",
  },
});
```

This is example of what is happening when I use it [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GBiA.png)

I used backgroundColor:'green' to see the vertical space and its too much.

I want to control the spacing between my Text elements. I am new to react-native any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, the lineHeight property is set to a multiple of the font size.

You may add `{lineHeight: fontSize}` (or any else desired amount) to **combinedStyles** to set it yourself.

```
 const combinedStyles = [
    styles.defaultText,
    style,
    isBold && styles.boldText,
    isItalic && styles.italicText,
    { fontSize: fontSize },
    { color: color ?? "black" },
    { lineHeight: fontSize },
  ];
```

Also try setting  **paddingTop** or **paddingBottom** or **marginTop** or **marginBottom** separately as may those are defined somewhere else which overrides the general padding and margin.

Also set `includeFontPadding: false` as there may be a default font padding.

Comment: I tried all of these

Comment: inspect the rendered element with computed style and find which rule is overriding all other rules? @AashishPal